# How can I make that C can apart letters from an word

Tags: c, function

First of all sorry for the hazy title and if my question isn't understood .English is my third  language and is kinda hard to formulate  the question clearly  . Here's my problem I want to introduce a chemical substance formula like H3PO4 and the the program should separate H and to give him a variable name like x(and we will have 3x because  its H3) and PO4 to be another variable like y. Or a simpler substance like HCl and the program should separate it in H and Cl .

Comment: It will need to be reasonably complicated because you are separating the elements of `HCl` but not those of `PO`. What have you tried?

Comment: The atomic symbols in chemistry have this very nice property that they all start with one capital letter, and may be followed by lowercase letters.  Therefore every capital letter is a new symbol.  However you seem to be interested in ions such as PO4(-3) rather than atoms only?  For that you will need some premade list of common ions.  Or else require your input to use some parentheses, e.g. H3(PO4), which are needed anyway when you have a repeat count on an entire ion.

Comment: [Phosphoric Acid is electrifying :)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoric_acid_fuel_cell)

Answer (score 3):

You can decompose the chemical formula by testing for capital letters, lower case letters and digits:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element {
    char symbol[3];
    int n;
};

// decompose a formula into an array of elements and counts
int decompose(char *s, struct element *a, int length) {
    int i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        if (isupper((unsigned char)*s) && i < length) {
            int j = 0;
            a->symbol[j++] = *s++;
            if (islower((unsigned char)*s)) {
                a->symbol[j++] = *s++;
            }
            a->symbol[j] = '\0';
            a->n = 1;
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)*s)) {
                a->n = strtol(s, &s, 10);
            }
            i++;
            a++;
        } else {
            return -1;  // syntax error
        }
    }
    return i;  // number of elements
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct element array[10];
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int n = decompose(argv[i], array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array));
        if (n < 0) {
            printf("%s: syntax error\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf("%s:\n", argv[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                printf("    %d %s\n", array[j].n, array[j].symbol);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./chem HCl H3PO4 XePtF6
1 H
1 Cl
H3PO4:
3 H
1 P
4 O
XePtF6:
1 Xe
1 Pt
6 F
```

Comment: That's what we call a full program! ;) I think misread what he needs, my program only store the different atoms, but it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will have the input in uppercases:

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int var[26];
    memset(var, 0, sizeof(var));
    char *s = "H3PO4";
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ) {
        char c = s[i++];
        int n = 1;
        if (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])) {
            n = 0;
            while (isdigit((unsigned char)s[i]))
                n = n * 10 + s[i++] - '0';
        }
        var[c - 'A'] += n;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <26; i++)
        if (var[i])
            printf("Atom %c: %d\n", i  + 'A', var[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
gcc chemistry.c && ./a.out 
Atom H: 3
Atom O: 4
Atom P: 1
```

Comment: `s[i] && isdigit(s[i])` is redundant: `isdigit(0)` is false anyway. Just write `isdigit((unsigned char)s[i])`

Comment: Also note that not all chemical elements symbols have a single letter, eg: `Cl` for *chlorine*, `Na` for *nitrogen*... But they all start with a capital letter optionally followed by a lower case letter as can be seen on the [Mendeleev Periodic Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table). Super heavy elements had a symbol with 2 lowercase letters until they all were officially named in 2016. Elements of [the hypothetical eight row](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_periodic_table) have such symbols but are unlikely to occur in any chemical formula.